# How to compare filenames with difference in special character encoding?

Tags: node.js, typescript, encoding

I am working with a system that syncs files between two vendors. The tooling is written in Javascript and does a transformation on file names before sending it to the destination. I am trying to fix a bug in it that is failing to properly compare file names between the origin and destination.

The script uses the file name to check if it's on destination
For example:
The following file name contains a special character that has different encoding between source and destination.

```
source:               Chinchón.jpg // hex code: o&#x301; 
destination :         Chinchón.jpg // hex code: 0xf3
```

The function that does the transformation is:

```
export const normalizeText = (text:string) =>  text
  .normalize('NFC')
  .replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
  .replace(/\u{2019}/gu, "'")
  .replace(/\u{ff1a}/gu, ":")
  .trim()
```

and the comparison is happening just like the following:

```
const array1 = ['Chinchón.jpg'];
console.log(array1.includes('Chinchón.jpg')); // false
```

Do I reverse the transformation before comparing? what's the best way to do that?

Comment: Normalize the text before comparing?

Comment: I was going down that path and kept giving me false until now.https://jsfiddle.net/4bfsegqy/ I think it's the monday effect

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right:

```js
// prepare dictionary
const rawDictionary = ['Chinchón.jpg']
const dictionary = rawDictionary.map(x => normalizeText(x))

...

const rawComparant = 'Chinchón.jpg'
const comparant = normalizeText(rawComparant)
console.log(rawSources.includes(comparant))
```